# What do we mean by Over Payment in Payslip

Tags: india, payment, inr-indian-rupee, deduction

i just got my salary and noticed that there is deduction of some amount under **Over Payment**. The salary slip is given in the form of a table. The table has 4 columns and many rows. For the purpose of this question, i am showing one column where the deduction was made.

| Advance |
| --- |

| Particular | AMT | Bal AMT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GPF ADV | 0 | 0 |
| HBA ADV | 0 | 0 |
| PAY ADV | 0 | 0 |
| OVER PAYMENT | 9005 | 0 |
| OMCA INT | 0 | 0 |

The above is just one column among 4. As we can see, the amount corresponding to **over payment** is 9005. And this was deducted from my total salary. For example, say my original(without any deduction) salary is 50000. Then after the above deduction i actually got 40995. **My question is** what do we mean by over payment? I mean why was this deduction made from my salary. And is there a way to not have this deduction in my salary. I mean there were other deductions as well in my salary like tax deduction etc which i was able to understand. But this one "over payment" i don't understand.

I work as an indian government employee in the Central Armed Police Force.

Comment: Is it possible your employer overpaid you in a previous month? I'd have expected them to notify you of this though.

Comment: Did you ask your payroll department?

Comment: Over 9000.... Just had to mention it....

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg the OP is in India, and so that's rupees at around 75-100 per $/£/€

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg: Actually the OP had the scouter upside down, it is 2006...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An "overpayment" almost always means that you were paid too much previously and now they are taking back the excess amount.

If your payslip has running totals like "year to date" you may be able to work out what category the excess amount was in. In any case, ask your employer what the reason was.

Comment: They should normally also have re-issued prior payslip(s) which were incorrect with the right amounts. Unless the amounts on the payslip(s) were correct, and it was just the payment which was incorrect.

Comment: This just happened to me. I got a pay raise, and payroll thought it was retroactive to January, so she added an extra amount to my March pay. Then she learned it wasn't retroactive, so she warned me that my April pay will have this deducted.

Comment: If it's more than a trivial amount, they probably ought to have given you advance notice too.